# Tornado url regex unicode chars

Tags: python, regex, unicode, tornado

I have a tornado application, where the url is something like

`https://example.com/my/path/❤`

In tornado I have

```
handlers = [
        (r'/my/path/❤$', MyHandler),
]
```

but it is not matching with the path.

I tried `tornado.escape.utf8()` and `tornado.escape.url_escape()` with no luck.

If I replace `%E2%9D%A4` which is encoded string of `❤` then it works is it possible to make it work without replacing it to encoded string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, tornado's routing engine currently works on the encoded form of the urls, so it is impractical to use non-ascii characters in routes. (They work fine if captured as a variable part of the path, so `r'/my/path/(.*)'` would correctly capture `❤` and pass it as the first argument to the handler).

Handling unicode routes is a [longstanding feature request](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/89), but it is difficult to solve correctly because of the complexity of the rules defined in RFC 3987.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I hope tornado gets this support soon,
Something like 
    handlers = [
        (r'/my/path/❤$', MyHandler, unicode=True),
   ]